# Reverse Proxy is set up on a server. Which redirect to a node js web applicaton. And the css and js of the application are not loaded

Tags: reverse-proxy, node.js

The node js web application is running on a server. 
e.g : https://9.55.168.37/myapp

There is a server (https://9.51.168.47) where a reverse proxy is set up and configured to redirect to the node js application. When we hit the url https://9.51.168.47/myapp , it eventually shows the content of the https://9.55.168.37/myapp

The content is showing and the functions are working fine. But the css and js files are not loaded. The errors are as follows:

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://9.51.168.47/myapp/css/common.css"

I have added the express static mapping as

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname+'/../../public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname+'/../../public/css')));

Please help me to find a clue why it is happening. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please provide some more information? Which web server are you using for reverse proxying node js application?Is it Apache or Nginx?

Comment: I am using IBM Security Access Manager Server. There I set up a reverse proxy and added a junction /myapp.

Comment: The issue is solved by adding the following mapping.
app.use('/myapp/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname+'/../../public/css'))); Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by adding the mapping in server.js

```
const app = express()
app.use('/myapp/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname+'/../../public/css')));
```

> That helps to map https://9.51.168.47/myapp/css (reverse proxy host) to https://9.55.168.37/myapp/css (app running host)

In the HTML page , the css is loaded as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../myapp/css/common.css">
```